# Name is not showing in dropdown php

Tags: php

I am trying to inflate the dropdown in php. It is not showing me the  value in dropdown. But when I see the source it is showing me there. When I see the source its show me the value like this

```
<select name="choose" id="chooseme">
  Urban Striped Sleeveless<option value="48514" name=""> </option>Black Leather High Top Sneakers<option value="19264" name=""> </option>Navy Knit Cardigan<option value="19263" name=""> </option>.....
```

Following is the code which I am using..

```
<?php
      var_dump($_GET["id"]);

      $args = array( 'post_type' => array('product') ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
          $loop->the_post();
         //echo '<option value="one">one</option>';
            $title = the_title();
            $value =$loop->post->ID;
       echo "<option value='$value'> $title </option>";

      endwhile;
      ?>
```

Comment: Try to concatenate the string  `<option value='$value'>".$title."</option>` or `<option value='$value'>{$title}</option>`

Comment: echo `'<option value=" '.$value.' "> '.$title.' </option>';`

Comment: @azad chouhan don't you think you need to use `get_the_title()` instead `the_title()` because you need to return value of title as per your code as i given in answer

Comment: @azad chouhan, have you tried with my answer? it should work.

Comment: please see the output here http://thebestofcards.com/choose-card-templates/?id=18933 @AlbertAkki

Comment: @azad chouhan, but have you tried with `get_the_title()` instead `the_title()`?

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the dropdown working:

```
<select name="drpDown">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

// here value is what we get when we refer it using its name "drpDown" and the text passed between <option> #### </option> is the text that is shown in drop down.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to avoid confusion between  quote

```
<?php
          var_dump($_GET["id"]);

          $args = array( 'post_type' => array('product') ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
              $loop->the_post();
             //echo '<option value="one">one</option>';
                $title = the_title();
                $value =$loop->post->ID;
                ?>
         <option value='<?php echo $value; ?>'> <?php echo $the_title; ?> </option>
    <?php
          endwhile;
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have syntax error !

Try to always use variable like :

```
".$variable."
```

In your case :

```
echo "<option value='".$value."'>" .$title. "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
?php
  var_dump($_GET["id"]);

  $args = array( 'post_type' => array('product') ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
      $loop->the_post();
     //echo '<option value="one">one</option>';
        $title = the_title();
        $value =$loop->post->ID;
   echo "<option value='$value'> ".$title."</option>";

  endwhile;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below mention code :
    
         array('product') ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
              $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

```
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
              $loop->the_post();
                $title = the_title();
                $value =$loop->post->ID; ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"> <?php echo $title; ?> </option>
    <?php
          endwhile;
          ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. you need to retrive value of title like `get_the_title()` while you have used `the_title()` that will print value

```
<?php
      var_dump($_GET["id"]);

      $args = array( 'post_type' => array('product') ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
          $loop->the_post();
         //echo '<option value="one">one</option>';
            $title = get_the_title(); // this will return the value of title
            $value = $loop->post->ID;
       echo "<option value='$value'> $title </option>";

      endwhile;
      ?>
```

Ref links

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Answer (score 0):

```
Just to avoid confusion, please separate the HTML and PHP. Like this:

<?php
      var_dump($_GET["id"]);

      $args = array( 'post_type' => array('product') ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      $posts = "";
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
          $loop->the_post();
          $title = the_title();
          $value =$loop->post->ID;
          $posts .= "<option value='" . $value . "'>" . $title . "</option>";

      endwhile;
?>

<select name="choose" id="chooseme">
    <?php echo $posts; ?>
</select>
```

Hope it helps.